# How to display unique elements of an array using Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter, nsarray

I have a formula retuning an array as example `var Array = [a,s,d,s,f,g,g,h,e]`.  What I want is to run a `for` loop or some other option that gives me back `a,s,d,f,g,h,e` - only the unique values.  How can I do this with ios Swift?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## If you don't care about order:

Simply use a set:

```
let set: Set = ["a", "s", "d", "s", "f", "g" , "g", "h", "e"]
print(set) // ["a", "s", "f", "g", "e", "d", "h"]
```

## If you care about the order:

Use this extension, which allows you to remove duplicate elements of any `Sequence`, while preserving order:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var alreadyAdded = Set<Iterator.Element>()
        return self.filter { alreadyAdded.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}

let array = ["a", "s", "d", "s", "f", "g" , "g", "h", "e"]
let result = array.unique()
print(result) // ["a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "e"]
```

Comment: i think, if change alreadyAdded type to Array, it will be faster.

Comment: @masakih What makes you suspect that? Sets have `O(1)` look ups (needed for fast `contains(_:)` calls), whereas array have O(n) loop ups in the general case

Comment: sorry! i was focusing on `insert(_:)` only. but i had overlooked `contains(_:)`.

Comment: @masakih `insert(_:)` is also constant time for sets, too.

Comment: i checked which fast are `Array.append(_:)` and `Set.insert(_:)`.  `Array.append(_:)` uses half time of `Set.insert(_:)`. 　of course, in this case Set is best. [https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58d9e75c50cb957f193a78d9]

Comment: I never said that they're the same speed. I just said that they're both `O(1)`.

Comment: @masakih Try an array with 100,000 elements, see how that goes