# How to remove duplicate characters from a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string

ruby has the function string.squeeze, but I can't seem to find a swift equivalent.

For example I want to turn bookkeeper -> bokepr

Is my only option to create a set of the characters and then pull the characters from the set back to a string?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit/update: **Swift 4.2 or later**

You can use a set to filter your duplicated characters:

```
let str = "bookkeeper"
var set = Set<Character>()
let squeezed = str.filter{ set.insert($0).inserted } 

print(squeezed)   //  "bokepr"
```

---

Or as an extension on `RangeReplaceableCollection` which will also extend String and Substrings as well:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Hashable {
    var squeezed: Self {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return filter{ set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

---

```
let str = "bookkeeper"
print(str.squeezed)      //  "bokepr"
print(str[...].squeezed) //  "bokepr"
```

Comment: This was what I was thinking, but it wasn't this clean. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would use this piece of code from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579948/3141234), which removes all duplicates of a sequence (keeping only the first occurrence of each), while maintaining order.

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var alreadyAdded = Set<Iterator.Element>()
        return self.filter { alreadyAdded.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

I would then wrap it with some logic which turns a String into a sequence (by getting its `characters`), unqiue's it, and then restores that result back into a string:

```
extension String {
    func uniqueCharacters() -> String {
        return String(self.characters.unique())
    }
}

print("bookkeeper".uniqueCharacters()) // => "bokepr"
```

Comment: How is this efficient as related to my answer below ? I would guess that it is as expensive as using reduce ?

Comment: @Sandeep This is is a linear time algorithm. Each `contains` call is called on a set, which is `O(1)`, unlike `String.range(of:)`, which is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found online, however I don't think it is optimal.

```
    func removeDuplicateLetters(_ s: String) -> String {
    if s.characters.count == 0 {
        return ""
    }

    let aNum = Int("a".unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.map{$0.value}.first!)
    let characters = Array(s.lowercased().characters)
    var counts = [Int](repeatElement(0, count: 26))
    var visited = [Bool](repeatElement(false, count: 26))
    var stack = [Character]()
    var i = 0

    for character in characters {
        if let num = asciiValueOfCharacter(character) {
            counts[num - aNum] += 1
        }
    }

    for character in characters {
        if let num = asciiValueOfCharacter(character) {
            i = num - aNum
            counts[i] -= 1
            if visited[i] {
                continue
            }
            while !stack.isEmpty, let peekNum = asciiValueOfCharacter(stack.last!), num < peekNum && counts[peekNum - aNum] != 0 {
                visited[peekNum - aNum] = false
                stack.removeLast()
            }
            stack.append(character)
            visited[i] = true
        }
    }

    return String(stack)
}

func asciiValueOfCharacter(_ character: Character) -> Int? {
    let value = String(character).unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.first?.value ?? 0
    return Int(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this using reduce(),

```
let newChar = str.characters.reduce("") { partial, char in
  guard let _ = partial.range(of: String(char)) else {
    return partial.appending(String(char))
  }
  return partial
}
```

As suggested by Leo, here is a bit shorter version of the same approach,

```
let newChar = str.characters.reduce("") { $0.range(of: String($1)) == nil ? $0.appending(String($1)) : $0 }
```

Comment: Works, but pretty expensive.

Comment: shorter `let newChar = str.characters.reduce("") { $0.range(of: String($1)) == nil ? $0.appending(String($1)) : $0 }`

Comment: Yeah that is definitely shorter but a bit less readable. I will put it to my answer.

Comment: or using contains instead of range of string `let newChar = str.characters.reduce("") { $0.characters.contains($1) ? $0 : "\($0)\($1)" }`

Comment: That also makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just Another solution

```
let str = "Bookeeper"
let newChar = str.reduce("" , {
    if $0.contains($1) {
        return "\($0)"
    } else {
      return "\($0)\($1)"
    }
})

print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeDuplicateLetters(_ inputString: String) -> String {
    var result = ""
    var seen = Set<Character>()
    
    for char in inputString {
        if !seen.contains(char) {
            seen.insert(char)
            result.append(char)
        }
    }
    
    return result
}

let input = "programming"
let output = removeDuplicateLetters(input)
print(output) // Output will be "progamin"
```

Interview iOS [Swift DSA Algo](https://www.appcodezip.com/search/label/Swift-Interview?&max-results=20)

Answer (score -1):

Use filter and contains to remove duplicate values

```
let str = "bookkeeper"
let result = str.filter{!result.contains($0)}
print(result) //bokepr
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do this with `continue`-

```
func removeDuplicateLetters(_ inputString: String) -> String {
  var seenChars: Set<Character> = []
  var result = ""
  for char in inputString {
    if seenChars.contains(char) {
      continue
    }
    seenChars.insert(char)
    result.append(char)
  }
  return result
}

let result = removeDuplicateLetters("bookkeeper")
print(result)// Output: "bokepr"
```