# How to remove duplicate of a specific character in the string on swift?

Tags: swift, string, duplicates

I have a string of `11223.3445566.7788.9900` now I want to create a function where I can remove the duplicate of the specific character in that string and leave only the first in the left.

This is my example code on how for better explanation

```swift
let string = "11223.3445566.7788.9900"

let removedDuplicate = removeDuplicate(string: string, char: ".")

print(removedDuplicate) // result 11223.344556677889900
```

You see, Unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903113) I only need to remove the duplicate of the specific character in the string, not all duplicated characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the position of the first occurrence of the specific character and then remove all other occurrences after that position:

```
func removeDuplicate(string: String, char: Character) -> String {
    if var idx = string.firstIndex(of: char) {
        string.formIndex(after: &idx)
        var s = string
        s.replaceSubrange(idx..., with: s[idx...].filter { $0 != char })
        return s
    } else {
        return string
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let string = "11223.3445566.7788.9900"
print(removeDuplicate(string: string, char: "."))
// 11223.344556677889900
```

Comment: or simply `return string[...idx] + string[idx...].filter{$0 != char}`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Yes, that is another option. I just wonder why the substring concatenation returns a `String`  and not a `SubString` ...

Comment: @LeoDabus: Now I see it: `string[idx...].filter()` returns a `String`, and there is an overload of `+` taking a sequence as first argument, a String as second argument, and returning a String

Comment: When extending StringProtocol If I constrain it to RangeReplaceableCollection it does allow me to concatenate two subsequences `static func + <Other>(lhs: Self.SubSequence, rhs: Other) -> Self.SubSequence where Other : RangeReplaceableCollection, Self.Element == Other.Element`

Comment: Funny thing when extending StringProtocol and constraining it to RangeReplaceableCollection it returns a subsequence even when using filter. Filter returns Self so if you apply it to a subsequence it returns a subsequence.

Comment: I still don't understand why when applying filter to a subsequence (result of a subscript range) of a string returns a string while applying the filter to self subscript (subsequence as well) in a StringProtocol instance method returns a subsequence. Do you mind expanding on that?

Comment: @LeoDabus: Check this https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/10871: *“Per guidance in SE-163 that methods that return new strings shouldn't return substrings, Substring shouldn't just take the default for RangeReplaceableCollection.filter of returning Self”*

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. If I understood it correctly The filter being called when applying to a substring it is not the same of the one called on a subsequence. There is probably a filter method declared in Substring type.

Comment: Found it https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Substring.swift   `public func filter(
    _ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> String {
    return try String(self.lazy.filter(isIncluded))
  }`

Comment: @LeoDabus: That is what I meant,  it was added with the pull request from my above link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`components(separatedBy:)`** and **`joined()`** to get that working,

```
func removeDuplicate(string: String, char: String) -> String {
    let arr = string.components(separatedBy: char)
    var result = arr[0]
    if arr.count > 1 {
        result += char + arr[1]
    }
    if arr.count > 2 {
        result += arr[2...].joined()
    }
    return result
}
```